# Fast way to find all instances of an image in an image? Core Image? OpenCV?

Tags: objective-c, opencv, core-image

I wrote code that loops through a video feed of a computer screen and recognizes certain PNG images by looping through pixels. I get 60fps with 250% CPU usage(1280x800 video feed). The code is a blend of Objective-C and C++.

I'm trying to find a faster alternative. Can Core Image detect instances of an image within another image and give me the pixel location? If not, is OpenCV fast enough to do that kind of processing at 60fps?

If Core Image and OpenCV aren't the correct tools, is there another tool that would be better suited?

(I haven't found any documentation showing Core Image can do what I need, I am trying to get a OpenCV demo working to benchmark)

Comment: what about using jpg with slight compression? last time i checked, jpg's are a lot smaller than png's.

Comment: openCV matchTemplate function is what you are looking for, but it might be slower (since it computes at least squared difference and maybe doesnt use multi-threading), but you could give it a try.

Comment: Just tried OpenCV, I get 9fps.

I might try using OpenGL and making a shader that takes two textures and returns an array of position match positions.